# Why does my Hash not get filled when initializing with a default object

Tags: ruby, hash

Given this code:

```
h = Hash.new([])

3.times do |i|
  h[:a] << i
end
```

I expect `h` to be `{:a => [0, 1, 2]}`, but it is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a great interview question for Ruby devs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the [API](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-c-new) says:

> If obj is specified, this single object will be used for all default
>   values.

With a small rewrite of your code, it should become clear what happens:

```
a = []
h = Hash.new(a)
3.times { |i| h[:a] << i }

# This is like:
# 3.times { |i| a << i }
# because `h` does not respond to your key :a

h
# => {} 
a
# => [0, 1, 2]
```

What you want to do, is this:

```
h = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
3.times { |i| h[:a] << i }

h
# => {:a=>[0, 1, 2]}
```